# HTML5 audio fires pause event while seeked

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, seekbar

i'm building a Audio-Playlist with a native `<audio>` element. Somethimg like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="audio-player">
  <audio id="audio" controls="controls">
    <source src="0.mp3" >       
  </audio>
  <button id="button0" data-track-url="0.mp3">Play 0</button>
  <button id="button1" data-track-url="1.mp3">Play 1</button>
  <button id="button2" data-track-url="2.mp3">Play 2</button>
</div>
```

I have some eventListeners on the buttons. If i click the one of the Buttons the right mp3 plays in the audio Element.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
for (var i = 0; i < my_buttons.length; i++) {         
   my_buttons[i].addEventListener("click", buttonClickAction, false);       
}
```

I also have added a eventListener to the play and pause event of the `<audio>` element so the two Buttons(Native Play/Pause and the `<button>`) have the same behavior.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
audio.addEventListener("play", audioPlayAction, false);
audio.addEventListener("pause", audioPauseAction, false);
```

Now I have the following Problem:

If I press a Button the equivalent track starts to play. If I then seek the timebar of the native Player a "pause" and a "start" event is fired by the `<audio>` element. Is it possible to prevent the "pause/start" event to be fired on seeking? Or is it possible to distinguish a normal "pause/start" Event from a seeking "pause/start" event?

I hope there is a solution.

greetings

**EDIT**

So you can see what exactly my Problem is, check out this snippet. There is a flickering in the button the moment I start to seek:

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("audio"),
    button = document.getElementById("button"),
    isPlaying = false;

var initPlayer = function() {
  audio.addEventListener("play", audioPlayAction, false);
  audio.addEventListener("pause", audioPauseAction, false);
  audio.addEventListener("seeking", audioSeekingAction, false);
  audio.addEventListener("seeked", audioSeekedAction, false);
  button.addEventListener("click", buttonClickAction, false);
},
buttonClickAction = function(event) {
  if(isPlaying){
    audio.pause();
    button.classList.add("is-playing");
  }else{
    audio.play();
    button.classList.remove("is-playing");
  }
},
audioPlayAction = function(event) {
  button.classList.add("is-playing");
  isPlaying = true;
  
},
audioPauseAction = function(event) {
  button.classList.remove("is-playing");
  isPlaying = false;
},
audioSeekingAction = function(event) {
  event.target.play()
},
audioSeekedAction = function(event) {
  event.target.play() 
};

initPlayer();
```

```css
.button-pause {
  display:none;    
}
.is-playing .button-pause {
  display:inline-block;
}
.button-play {
  display:inline-block;
}
.is-playing .button-play {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls="controls" preload="none" >
  <source src="https://archive.org/download/calexico2006-12-02..flac16/calexico2006-12-02d1t02.mp3" >  
</audio><br>
<button id="button">
  <span class="button-play">PLAY</span>
  <span class="button-pause">PAUSE</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I have this exact problem. Too bad no answer :(